# Net::OpenSSH; rsync_put writes progress into file, scp_put doesn't

Tags: perl, scp, openssh, tty

`rysnc_put` and `scp_put` both show the progress in the terminal.
But when i try to write it into a file i can only see the progress from `rysnc_put`. The problem remains even if i just print the output from the pty [my edit].
Is this a problem with my `pty` usage?
It is only mentioned for `scp_put`, that there is no progress when the `STDOUT` is not a `tty`.

> Note that scp will not generate progress reports unless its stdout stream is attached to a tty.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $SSH = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    '192.168.178.33',
    (
        user => 'TT',
        password => 'TTpassword',
        port => '22',
    )
);

my $pty = new IO::Pty;
my $slave = $pty->slave;

$SSH->scp_put(
    {
        quiet => 0,
        verbose => 1,
        stdout_fh => $pty,
        stderr_fh => $pty,
        bwlimit => '200',
    },
    '/opt/TT/CHANGES.md',
    '/opt/TT/CHANGES.md',,
);

while (<$pty>) {
    print STDOUT "$_";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution to your problem is to customize the pure perl implementation of the SCP protocol available from [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Any).

I designed the SCP classes from that package to be subclassed so that things like that could be done but never went to actually document that API, so, well, you would be relying on undocumented features (though, I don't plan to change it).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyPutter {
    use parent 'Net::SSH::Any::SCP::Putter::Standard';

    use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

    for my $name (qw(open_dir open_file close_file close_dir)) {
        my $method = $name;
        my $super = Net::SSH::Any::SCP::Putter::Standard->can($name);
        no strict 'refs';
        *$name = sub {
            my ($putter, $a) = @_;
            print STDERR "$method $a->{path} --> $a->{local_path}\n";
            $super->(@_);
        };
    }

    sub read_file {
        my $putter = shift;
        my $a = shift;
        my $data = $putter->SUPER::read_file($a, @_);
        $a->{bytes_copied} += length($data);
        print STDERR "read_file $a->{path} --> $a->{local_path} $a->{bytes_copied}/$a->{size}\n";
        return $data;
    }
};

use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("localhost");

my $any = $ssh->any;
my $putter = MyPutter->_new($any, {}, "/tmp/out2", "/tmp/passwd3");
$putter->run({})
```

Comment: That is an impressive amount of help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Even if `scp_put` and `rsync_put` are similar methods, they wrap two unrelated programs (`scp` and `rsync`) which regarding that matter, do not behave in the same way.

Specifically, `scp` checks whether its stdio streams are attached to a pty and when not, it suppresses progress messages. AFAIK that feature can not be disabled.

**Update**: Reading from the PTY in parallel:

This code reads from the PTY and writes the data to a file in parallel:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;
use POSIX ();
use IO::Pty;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("localhost"); #, scp_cmd => "/home/salva/t/openssh-8.9p1/scp");

my $pty = new IO::Pty;
my $slave = $pty->slave;
print "slave: $slave, fd: ".fileno($slave)."\n";

my $logger_pid = fork;
unless ($logger_pid) {
  defined $logger_pid or die "fork failed: $!";

  open my $log, ">", "/tmp/scp.log";
  select $log;
  $| = 1;

  print("Reading from PTY\n");
  while (1) {
      my $buffer;
      sysread($pty, $buffer, 1);
      syswrite($log, $buffer, 1);
  }
  print "PTY closed unexpectedly\n";
  POSIX::_exit();
}


my $scp_pid = fork;
unless($scp_pid) {
    defined $scp_pid or die "fork failed: $!";

    $pty->make_slave_controlling_terminal();
    $ssh->scp_put({stdout_fh => $slave,
                   stderr_fh => $slave,
                   quiet => 0},
                  "/etc/passwd", "/tmp/foo.vdi");
}

waitpid($scp_pid, 0);

kill 9, $logger_pid;
waitpid($logger_pid, 0);
```

Comment: I saw this profile image a lot the last days, thank you for answering. So far what you said is clear, but i did attach a pty to its output.

Comment: Oh, I see, ptys don't work that way! `open $pty, '>&STDOUT'` closes the old file handle in `$pty` and then attaches it to a newly created copy of `STDOUT`. AFAIK, there is no way to redirect a pty output to some file other than doing it explicitly on your program by reading and writting inside a loop!

Comment: Okay, so i edited my question and print the output at the end. I Still get everything but the progress. But this is what you meant, right?

Comment: Not exactly, because you should run the loop in parallel with the `scp` command, otherwise it could block. Also, you have to pass `$slave` as the `stdout` and `stderr` file handles instead of `$pty`.

Comment: Would be great, if you could give me an example how to do that, or give me some hint what i have to search for to find the right way to do it. Either way, i'll still give it a day and will accept your answer if nothing better comes along. Thanks

Comment: @testcaseone, see my updated answer. Even if it is not working I think it is the way to go, but `scp` should be doing some extra check...

Comment: `scp` is also checking that the PTY  process group owner and the SCP one are the same so that transfers don't get interrupted when they are sent into the background. I have updated the code on my answer with a workaround for that. IMO, that approach is pretty complex and I would try to avoid it!